# How can I lazily import a module in python?

Tags: python

I have classes which require dependencies in order to be instantiated but are otherwise optional. I'd like to lazily import the dependencies and fail to instantiate the class if they aren't available. Note that these dependencies are not required at the package level (otherwise they'd be mandatory via setuptools). I currently have something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            import module
        except ImportError:
            raise ModuleNotFoundError("...")

    def foo(self):
        import module
```

Because this try/except pattern is common, I'd like to abstract it into a lazy importer. Ideally if `module` is available, I won't need to import it again in `Foo.foo` so I'd like `module` to be available once it's been imported in `__init__`. I've tried the following, which populates `globals()` and fails to instantiate the class if `numpy` isn't available, but it pollutes the global namespace.

```
def lazy_import(name, as_=None):
    # Doesn't handle error_msg well yet
    import importlib
    mod = importlib.import_module(name)
    if as_ is not None:
        name = as_
    # yuck...
    globals()[name] = mod

class NeedsNumpyFoo:
    def __init__(self):
        lazy_import("numpy", as_="np")

    def foo(self):
        return np.array([1,2,])
```

I could instantiate the module outside the class and point to the imported module if import doesn't fail, but that is the same as the `globals()` approach. Alternatively `lazy_import` could return the `mod` and I could call it whenever the module is needed, but this is tantamount to just importing it everywhere as before.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: can't you return the module and assign it to an attribute (`self.np = lazy_import(...)`), so in the method you would do sth like `return self.np.array(...)`

Comment: I could, but it is certainly not very conventional. Especially if the module is very heavy.

Comment: how would that differ from putting it in `globals`, you need to only access it in the instance anyways as I understand? I mean if you create multiple instances, then set it as class attribute

Comment: You seem to be making this needlessly complicated. Why catch `ImportError` just to raise `ModuleNotFoundError`? Just import at the scope where the module is required and be done with it.

Comment: @Woodford because they encode different semantics.

Comment: Pandas actually has a function `import_optional_dependency` which may make a good example https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6c1f6cccee6bbccfb29488a94664ed07db024d9/pandas/compat/_optional.py#L65 as used in `SQLAlchemyEngine` https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6c1f6cccee6bbccfb29488a94664ed07db024d9/pandas/io/sql.py#L1294

Comment: @erip `Import can't find module, or can't find name in module.` Since you're not importing a specific name from the module then the semantics in this case are identical.

Comment: @Woodford Yes, this is a minimal example but often we import names from modules. I don't think splitting hairs over the error raised is really the point in any case.

Comment: @ti7 That looks promising. It seems like they still need to import where needed, but I think that's probably as good as it's going to get. Feel free to add this as an answer if you'd like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas actually has a function `import_optional_dependency` which may make a good example ([link GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6c1f6cccee6bbccfb29488a94664ed07db024d9/pandas/compat/_optional.py#L65)) as used in `SQLAlchemyEngine` ([link GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6c1f6cccee6bbccfb29488a94664ed07db024d9/pandas/io/sql.py#L1294))

However, this is only used during class `__init__` to get a meaningful error (`raise ImportError(...)` by default!) or warn about absence or old dependencies (which is likely a more practical use of it, as older or newer dependencies may import correctly anywhere if they exist, but not work or be explicitly tested against or even be an accidental local import)

I'd consider doing similarly, and either not bother to have special handling or only do it in the `__init__` (and then perhaps only for a few cases where you're interested in the version, etc.) and otherwise simply import where needed

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, ...):
        import bar  # only tests for existence

    def usebar(self, value):
        import bar
        bar.baz(value)
```

---

Plausibly you could assign to a property of the class, but this may cause some trouble or confusion (as the import should already be available in `globals` once imported)

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, ...):
        import bar
        self.bar = bar

    def usebar(self, value):
        self.bar.baz(value)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I suspect this is about as good as it's going to get without resorting to magic. Appreciate the link!

Answer (score 0):

Gave it a quick test with a wrapper, seems to work fine:

```
def requires_math(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global math
        try:
            math
        except NameError:
            import math
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@requires_math
def func():
    return math.ceil(5.5)

print(func())
```

Edit: More advanced one that works with any module, and ensures it is a module in case it's been set to something else.

```
from types import ModuleType

def requires_import(*mods):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for mod in mods:
                if mod not in globals() or not isinstance(globals()[mod], ModuleType):
                    globals()[mod] = __import__(mod)
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@requires_import('math', 'random')
def func():
    return math.ceil(random.uniform(0, 10))

print(func())
```

Comment: what if `math` is defined as something else? it wouldn't raise the `NameError`, but later it could raise `AttributeError`

Comment: Unless you're thinking of something else, that would have to be defined in the global scope, and in doing so it would have broken a normal import too.

Comment: yes, I was thinking of something defined in global scope, why would it break an import?

Comment: I mean if you had `import math`, then `math = 2`, it would override the import anyway. Hence why I'm presuming I've misunderstood you haha.

Comment: that yes, I was just thinking if you have only `math = 2`, you wouldn't be able to import `math` because you wouldn't get a `NameError`, but I mean the likelihood of having a name that is the same as some module's is pretty low

Comment: Ah, what I was meaning, is if you had `math = 2`, no matter if you did my lazy import or a normal import, it'd potentially cause issues either way. Did an edit anyway

Comment: ah, right, if `math = 2` was being used as a variable somewhere else, importing would likely cause issues (due to type changes)